# De-serializing arbitrary date formats in JSON.net

Tags: c#, json.net

I am currently using an API that returns dates in various different formats (ideally, they would standardise their format), so I have put JsonConvertAttribute attributes on each property to deserialise them correctly like so:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(dMMyyyyWithSlashesConverter))]
public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }

[JsonConverter(typeof(MMyyyyWithSlashesConverter))]
public DateTime AnotherDate { get; set; }

[JsonConverter(typeof(yyyyMMWithoutSlashesConverter))]
public DateTime AnnoyingDate { get; set; }
```

So for every date format, I have to create a new converter class, e.g.

```
public class MMyyyyWithSlashesConverter: CustomDateConverter
{
    public MMyyyyWithSlashesConverter() : base("MM/yyyy")
    {
    }
}
```

Which makes for some pretty ugly and repetitive code. I would much rather be able to do something like

```
[ParseDateAs("d/MM/yyyy")]
public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }

[ParseDateAs("MM/yyyy")]
public DateTime AnotherDate { get; set; }

[ParseDateAs("yyyyMM")]
public DateTime LessAnnoyingDate{ get; set; }
```

The only way I can think of is to modify the JSON.net source to pass property parameters through to the ReadJson function on JsonConverter, which I will do if there isn't a solution which doesn't involve me modifying the source.

Comment: AFAIK, making custom converters like you are already doing is the only way to support arbitrary date formats per property without resorting to modifying the JSON.Net source code (or manually parsing out the JSON via JObjects).  If someone else knows differently, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: @BrianRogers Yeah, that's what I thought. It'd be nice if Json.net had a way of passing flags to converters via attributes, or being able to inherit from JsonConverterAttribute to implement that kind of behaviour oneself.

Comment: Even better would be if `Json.NET` supported something like [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)